# Combining two ode45 function answers into one plot

Tags: matlab, plot, ode, differential-equations

I am trying to use Matlab to solve a problem which has two separate differential equations that I want to return the values for over time in one giant plot.

For Example the first portion I want to do is:

```
ainitial = 0;
arange=[0 2];
[a,A] = ode45(@rkfunc, arange, ainitial);
```

Then I would like to start the next ode45 portion based on the last A value, so I try to set it as binitial.

```
binitial = A(end);
brange=[2 4];
[b,B] = ode45(@rkfunc, brange, binitial);
```

Then I would like to combine and plot the answers from [a,A] and [b,B] together into one giant plot, but I'm not sure how to go about doing that.

Any help would be appreciated.

Note: Edited to show binitial = A(end) instead of B(end) which fixes the numbers not overlapping from A(end) and the start of B.

Comment: I should note I have tried doing: plotOutput = [A B];
plot(plotOutput, '-o') - and that plots both on the same graph, but not in one straight line with the same color, and the end of A does not start the beginning of B.

Comment: it is declared as rkfunc(t,T)

Comment: @NickyMattsson, also fixed a typo to use A(end) instead of B(end)

Comment: 1 dimensional numbers.

Comment: RKFUNC returns a vector of length 0, but the length of initial conditions vector is 1. The vector returned by RKFUNC and the initial conditions vector must have the same number of elements.

Comment: @NickyMattsson, now since I've done that, it no longer allows me to run my previously working matlab file.

Comment: You are concatenating the vectors wrongly, which you would realise if you checked the size of `A` and the size of `B`.

Comment: Why not just `plot(a,A,'-ob',b,B,'-ob')` to plot both pieces in the same graph?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To concatenate two differently sized vectors you should use the syntax:

```
[A;B]
```

not

```
[A B]
```